# Should the chazzan say amen after the Priestly Blessing?

Tags: blessing, chazzan-prayer-leader, birchas-kohanim

The chazzan says the words of the [Priestly Blessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing) word after word, and Kohanim (priests) repeat after him.
Should the chazzan say "amen" after each blessing?
What about "amen" after the blessing that Kohanim say in  the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Orach Chaim 128:19 "Chazan does not say Amen after the Kohanim say the Beracha". Be'er Hataiv 34 says "that this is even the case if the Chazan is sure he will not get mixed up". Be'er Hataiv says further "that this is only on the Pesukim not on the original Beracha where there everyone says he should say Amen". However the Mishna Berura 71 says that if he is davening from a siddur and will not be confused he may say Amen. The Mishna Berura also brings down from the Ellya Rabba that there are those that hold you should not answer Amen on the original Beracha.

[הלכות נשיאת כפיס סיק קכח](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&hilite=6cf0afb4-2ff3-4df9-86a7-e171816a23a3&st=%d7%91%d7%a8%d7%9b%d7%aa+%d7%9b%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%9d&pgnum=10)

Comment: Arukh HaShulḥan brings those who say that you should answer amen to the אשר קדשנו bracha but not to the verses, and that seems to be the practice in his milieu.